# React: Re-rendering a page when passing an id parameter in the url

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React js, and i have a doubt:
in my index page i declare the routes, calling for the component

```
<Route path="/assignments/organization/:id" component={Manifest} />
```

In the "manifest" component, i have 2 components:

- a "sidebar" with the links
- a "feed" component that calls an api retrieving my information to build the list of assignments

my problem is that when i click on a link on the sidebar passing an id (ex: /assignments/organization/1234 ), the feed component does not make this new request to the api and hence, does not re-render the information linked to that id (if i press F5 to refresh the page, it does the request, but on clicking the link it just changes the id on the url on the browser, but it does nothing)

the links on the sidebar `<Link to={`/assignments/organization/${chl.id}`}>{chl.name}</Link>`

the feed code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import useApi from 'components/utils/useApi';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import FeedList from 'components/feed/feedList';

const Feed = () => {
    let location = useLocation();
    let path = (location.pathname).toLocaleLowerCase();
    let orgId = '';

    let pathArr = path.split('/assignments/')
    if(pathArr[1]) {
        if(pathArr[1].split('/')[1] && pathArr[1].split('/')[1] !== undefined && pathArr[1].split('/')[1] !== '' ) {
            orgId = 'Organization/'+pathArr[1].split('/')[1]
        } else {
            orgId = 'Organization/'
        }
    }

    let requestPath = (orgId) ? orgId : '';

    const mountRef = useRef(null);
    const [load, loadInfo] = useApi({
        debounceDelay: 300,
        url: `/Assignments/${requestPath}`,
        method: 'get',
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        load({
            debounced: mountRef.current,
        });

        if(!mountRef.current) {
            mountRef.current = true;
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="feed">
            <FeedList 
                cards={loadInfo.data} 
                loading={loadInfo.loading}
                error={loadInfo.error}
            />
        </div>
    )
};

export default Feed;
```

Comment: What does `useAPI(...)` returns? Your code seems more complicated than it should be. I can't see a reason why you have used `useRef()` hook and if you want access to the `id` param, why not use `useParams()` hook? You should change your code to make the API request whenever the `id` param changes. Currently, your code seems to make the request only once.

Comment: useApi returns a json. I tried using useParams, but it didnt re render

Answer (score 0):

I can not add a comment to your post but your useEffect() hook needs a dependency in its dependency array. With an empty array it only fires at the initial render. Using a dependency in the array, it will fire whenever the dependency changes.

So the code below will fire on initial render and whenever `id` changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
    load({
        debounced: mountRef.current,
    });

    if(!mountRef.current) {
        mountRef.current = true;
    }
}, [id]);
```

Similar logic can be applied to other hooks to make them fire whenever a dependency changes. More info in the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
        load({
            debounced: mountRef.current,
        });

        if(!mountRef.current) {
            mountRef.current = true;
        }
    }, []);
```

You need to add `requestPath` dependency here as this will only run once component mounts and do not run whenever any change happens.

Comment: Were do i get this dependency from, and how do i implement it?

Comment: `  }, []);`
Add `requestPath` inside the empty array